# Не работают создаваемые контроллеры в Laravel на Open Server

Tags: laravel, openserver, controller

При создании контроллеров в Laravel на Open Sever на каждый контроллер выдает все время такой самый ответ в ошибке. Имена файлов соответствуют имени контроллера опечаток нет. Ни один котроллер созданный в Laravel не отрабатывает, с пространством имен тоже ошибок нет.
Illuminate \ Contracts \ Container \ BindingResolutionException
PHP 8.1.9
10.37.3
Target class [PostController] does not exist.

Comment: Едва ли виноват OpenServer. Каким образом Вы создаете контроллеры, каким образом это "не отрабатывает" и так далее.

Comment: В IDE создаю файлы Controllers.php с префиксами или даже контроллеры , которые создаются в OpenServer через консоль все равно не работают . На все котроллеры в ответ сообщение Target class [HomeController] does not exist. К примеру в скобках указан Home Controller.

Comment: Может из-за того что на данный момент я использую версию Laravel 10.38?

Comment: Решение нашдось на сайте   https://laravel.demiart.ru/target-class-does-not-exist-in-laravel-8/?ysclid=lqex388c8n225928120

Comment: Ну так-то документация есть официальная [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing)